# how can we solve Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"?

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have a file in csv format which contains two columns: samples and status(pLGG and healthy)
Now I intend to add a column which turn 1 for pLGG samples and 0 for healthy ones.
In fact, I want to binarize my categorical variable for further analysis but I faced this error.
In the following I will add my codes and the final error.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
traitData = read.csv("traits.csv")


datTraits = as.data.frame(traitData)
rownames(datTraits)=traitData$sample
datTraits = subset(datTraits , select = -c(1))

collectGarbage()

library(dplyr)
traits = datTraits
mutate(disease_state_bin = ifelse(grepl("pLGG" , traits$status),1,0))
```

final error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Then I did the following changes and the result was as following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
mutate(disease_state_bin = ifelse(grepl("pLGG" , as.character(datTraits$status),1,0)))
```

last error :

```
Error in ifelse(grepl("pLGG", as.character(datTraits$status), 1, 0)) : 
argument "yes" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Please include your data using `dput()` and any other relevant code (e.g. `library()`).